# What is 1 and 2 when check KitKat Version on Sony Xperia

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, android-versions, sony-xperia

recently I saw on my friends mobile when checking KitKat version,

Friend 1 : Kitkat 4.2.2 shows Big '2' spinning (Sony Xperia E1 single sim)
  Friend 2 : Kitkat 4.4.4 show Big '1' spinning  (Sony Xperia M2 dual sim)

there is some screenshots. I wanna know what's the meaning of them ? I saw earlier big 'K' letter. but now '1' and '2'! complicated..

Can you help me to solve this ?

[image: kitkat version big letter 2]

[image: kitkat version big letter 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [AOSP source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-mr2.2-release/core/java/com/android/internal/app/PlatLogoActivity.java#L82), the big character shown at the first stage of the KitKat easter egg screen is the first character of the build ID. You can find the build ID (called “Build number”, but actually it is not just a number) on the **Settings** → **About phone** screen.

On Google Nexus devices the build ID for stock KitKat ROMs looks like `KTU84Q`, therefore the big letter on the easter egg screen will be “K”. In fact, the first letter of the Google build ID always matches the Android version code name, and the code structure is [documented](https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html).

Other manufacturers have their own build ID formats. E.g., for the Sony Xperia E1 model the build ID for one of KitKat ROM versions is 20.1.A.2.13, and for the Sony Xperia M2 Dual the build ID may be 18.3.1.B.0.18; this explains why the first model shows a big “2” on the screen, while the second shows “1”.

Comment: Wow you're great dear thanks! Your answer clear my all problems! thanks again! :D